# Clonar nó profundamente não funcionando corretamente

Tags: javascript, dom

Estou tentando duplicar a div `meta` de uma página de vídeo do Youtube. É a div abaixo da div do título do video e de like e dislike. Quero que fique com 2 iguais, uma em cima da outra.

Porém quando uso:

```
original = document.querySelectorAll('#meta');
clone = original[original.length-1].cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "meta1";
original[original.length-1].after(clone);
```

Ele duplica a div, mas as informações dentro dela(os filhos) não aparecem.

**EXEMPLO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "_Estou tentando duplicar a div meta de uma página de vídeo do Youtube_"... como assim?

Comment: @sam Acabei de atualizar a dúvida, espero que ajude.

Comment: Isso é um vídeo incorporado? Como é isso?

Comment: é uma página de video qualquer do youtube, por exemplo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM__lPTWThU

Comment: Cara, duplicando você deve estar. O problema é que vai além de simplesmente acrescentar a div abaixo da outra. Você vai ter que alterar o `css` e os comandos responsivos que o Youtube utiliza. Acredito que a questão seja ampla demais...

Comment: Me parece que a div é renderizada em tempo de execução. Vc pode até clonar, os dados estão todos no clone, mas os dados não aparecem porque são renderizados só no carregamento da página.

Comment: É estranho porque até onde eu sei, o clone profundo clona tudo. CSS, etc.. Já coloquei o mesmo ID, em vez de alterá-lo. Você pode ver o HTML todinho do node clonado igualzinho. Acho que o que pode ser é um JS complexo agindo ali. Conhecem alguma outra maneira de fazer o que pretendo?